Forked managed package permission sets
Has anyone had to deal with the challenge of maintaining custom permission sets cloned from managed package permission sets? As new versions of the managed package are released, the custom permission set has to be maintained to include any permissions for new components. Wondering if there is any tooling out there to manage this and how much of a problem it is in the community.
Thanks
